# How can I go two level back in perl using dirname?

Tags: perl, path, dirname

I have a value stored in a variable

```
$var1="/home/PPP/Testing/dir2/file1";
```

and this is a real path in my linux system.
Now, using the value of `$var1`, I want to extract the value of `$var2`.

I want "/home/PPP/Testing" in `$var2`. I can't put the string value directly in `$var2` because the path in `$var1` could vary. Like, it (`$var1`) could be "/home/PPP/Testing/dir2/file1", "/home/PPP/lnx/dir3/file4", "/home/PPP/window62/dir24/file1".

So, in all, I would want the path in `$var1` to get two levels back, and then is stored in `$var2`.

How can I do it? Can it be done using [dirname](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) ?

Comment: What is `dirname`? Have you considered `"$var1/../../"`?

Comment: @TLP, yes, I tried "$var1/../../". And people do have other work as well. Sitting all the time here is not feasible for all.

Comment: If you want good answers, you should stick around and answer follow-up questions. In 2 days, your question can be closed, and much fewer people will even see your question. The best time to get feedback to your question is the first few hours. That also goes for the people spending their time answering your questions. If they put in an answer, and only 2 days later can you say "Yes, this worked for me", they will not get as many upvotes or recognition. In fact, by that time, likely only a handful of other people will ever see it.

Comment: So, what is `dirname`? And why didn't `/../../` work?

Comment: Ok, so `dirname` is from `File::Basename` (we assume). So why are you asking us if it works? Haven't you tried it yourself? And why does not normal relative path handling work for you? `/../../`.

Comment: Yes, I am using File::Basename 's dirname. I asked because I didn't find any way to do it via dirname, and if I can find a new way here.

How can i implement /../../?

Comment: Just concatenate it to the end of the path. `$var2 = $var1 . "/../../"` should work fine. It works in Windows and in *nix. If you're having trouble with `dirname`, you should just post the code, with expected vs actual result. In most cases, just doing that will tell people exactly what you are doing and what is wrong. My warning lights went off last question when you said you could not chdir, but you never explained, so we didn't solve that mystery.

Answer (score 4):

A way to extract a part of the path is to parse it and then reassemble what is needed.

The easiest thing to recommend for parsing is a library for that job, like core [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Spec)

```
use File::Spec;

my @fqn = File::Spec->splitdir($var1);

my $var2 = File::Spec->catdir( @fqn[0..$#fqn-2] );
```

The `splitdir` returns an empty first element if the path starts with a `/` (by design), and since you precisely want to join these back that first empty element is just as needed. And then join up to the last two elements (filename and one dir to discard). The [variable `$#aryname`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%23) is the index of the last element in the array `aryname`.

There are yet other libraries of course, and then other ways.

One can manually split the path by `/` by `my @fqn = split m{/}, $var1`, where the first element is again an empty string if the path starts with `/`. Or use regex like `my @fqn = m{[^/]+}g` (now the first element isn't empty).  I don't see any advantages of these over a good library in this case.

Comment: `my $var2 = @fqn[0..$#fqn-2];` ...? You left out the `join` there, right? Or in this case, the `catdir`.

Comment: @zadmin, Is there a way to pass a delimiter in splitdir?

Comment: @PPP The delimiter is the delimiter used by the OS, `/` for *nix and `\` for windows. What other delimiter would you want and why?

Comment: @PPP  No, we can't change that -- `splitdir` uses the delimiter for the path suitable for the OS.  If you want different delimiters for some reason then you'd have to use other methods, like `split` or regex (which is why I show them, as more flexible ways to do this manually).  Why do you need that?

Comment: @zdim, just wanted to know for my knowledge. Thanks though!

Comment: @PPP OK. The point of the library is that it uses the right separator in the path for the OS it runs on. And as it is intended for work with the filesystem it doesn't allow us to choose a separator since the user could by a mistake choose a wrong one and thus end up with an invalid path. So it just sets the separator on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of doing it with [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3A%3ATiny#parent).  It's not in core Perl, but it's pretty nifty.

```
use Path::Tiny;

my $var1 = "/home/PPP/Testing/dir2/file1";
my $var2 = path($var1)->parent(2);
```